# SQL Query with Multiple Or On Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there is a way to write a statement with multiple OR in a better way.
For example if i want to Select the users with Username A,B,C,D,E,F,G.
With the SQL i already know i will write something like this

```
Select * From Users Where Username="A" OR Username="B".....
```

But if i had more usernames it will be a difficult to read statement.
I was wondering if there is a better way to write that:
Something like:Username={"A","B"....}
Thank you.

Comment: Do you always have a fixed, known number of Usernames? If not, perhaps think about embedding the SELECT statement in a FOR loop over the list of Usernames.

Comment: I dont know the number of names!In the for loop i wanted to avoid inserting "N" OR conditions where N is the number of names!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username IN ('A','B'...);
```

Answer (score 2):

USE - **IN**

```
 Select * From Users Where Username IN ("A","B"..)
```